# How to validate presence of one field in another model from one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one model PunchingRequest and one model PunchingInformation, In PunchingInformation i have two fields, punch_in_time and punch_out_time. I want to insert record in punching requests table if and only if atleast one out of punch_in_time or punch_out_time contains a value. I have a form containing fields related to both PunchingRequest and PunchingInformation. How can I impose this validation?

Comment: what is the relation between PunchingRequest and PunchingInformation ?

Comment: one punching request belongs to one punching information

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom validation like this:

```
validate :presence_of_punch_in_time_or_punch_out_time

def presence_of_punch_in_time_or_punch_out_time
  # Use PunchingInformation.where(...)
  # or this.your_object_relation_with_punching_information
  # to get the other model row.
  errors[:base] << "Wrong punching information" unless row.punch_in_time || row.punch_out_time
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write custom validation in the PunchingRequest model like

```
validate :validate_punching_information

def validate_punching_information
  errors[:base] << 'Either punch in or punch out should be present' if self.punching_information.punch_in_time.nil? && self.punching_information.punch_out_time.nil?
end
```

I am assuming that PunchingRequest and PunchingInformation are one to one related

Comment: I am getting this error
undefined method `punch_in_time' for nil:NilClass

Comment: if self.punching_information.try(:punch_in_time).nil? && self.punching_information.try(:punch_out_time).nil?

Comment: the above line will also validate presence of punching_information. since the requirement is to have either of punch_in or punch_out present, it makes sense to always have punching_information object associated.